# Custom http request returns an error in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two services

```
Http client service

 get(url):any{
  this.storage.get('token').then((name) => {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createGeneralHeaders(headers);
    return this.http.get(url+"?access-token="+name, {
      headers: headers
    });

});
```

And then i have this

```
  constructor( private _httpClient:HttpClient){}

  getTrucks():Observable<any>{
   return this._httpClient.get(this.trucksurl+"phone-trucks")  
       .map(res => res.json().data)  //returns an error

  }
```

The second service returns an error that cannot read property map of undefined

Comment: Format your code correctly please.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get(url)` method does not return anything. This is why you are experiencing this problem.

Also note that you should ***not*** be specifying the `any` type. The compiler would have caught this error for you had you let it infer the return type which would have been `void` but instead you specified the return type as `any`,  short-circuiting the type inference process for no reason.

I realize a lot of angular examples do this but those examples are not examples of good TypeScript code.

Assuming `http` in your first service is a reference to the official angular 2 http service you would want something like

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

export class HttpClient {
  get(url: string) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    this.createGeneralHeaders(headers);

    return Observable
      .fromPromise(this.storage.get('token'))
      .flatMap(
        name => this.http.get(`${url}?access-token=${name}`, {headers})
      );
  }
}
```

In your original code, `get` was not returning anything, and updating it to return the result of the `then` call would result in it returning a `Promise` to an `Observable` instead an `Observable`. Since the consuming code was calling `map` I assume the intention was to return an `Observable`. This can be achieved by using `Observable.fromPromise`. Another way would be to return an `Observable` directly from the storage service but not knowing the internals of that service the above option is simpler.

Comment: The use of get(url) is to attach the access token value, ive tried adding return at return this.storage.get.... but this fails to do the get http request. How can i format it to still attach the access token and still perform the http   get

Comment: I updated my answer but please keep in mind that it depends on the return values of storage.get and a few other or some shins about the correctness of various methods you haven't included

Comment: Now am gettinng an error that, Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Comment: the line `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';` specifically adds `flatMap` and `mergeMap`