# Retrieve the value of ionic2 storage and attach to a value fails

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a custom http service that attaches an access token to every request and i would like to use an access token from ionic2 storage value

This is the code from my two previous questions

So in the httpclient service i have

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
   authtoken: string;
   storage: Storage;

constructor(private http: Http, storage: Storage, private _authService:Authservice) {

  this._authService.tokenEvent.subscribe(res => {  //subscribing to token event in authservice
    if (res) {
      this.storage.get('token')
        .then(token => {
           this.authtoken = token
        });
      }
    })
  }

  get(url){
         let headers = new Headers();
      this.createGeneralHeaders(headers);
       return Observable
           .flatMap(   //retuns an error flatmap doesnt exist on observable
           name => this.http.get(`${url}?access-token=${this.authtoken}`, {headers})
       );

     }
```

In the authservice where am setting the token

```
 tokenEvent: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  login(user: UserModel): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post(this.loginurl + "mobile-login", body)
     .map((response: Response) => {
        let token = response.json().access_token;
       if (token) {
          this.storage.set('token', token).then(res => this.tokenEvent.next(true));
      return true;
    }
  })
//.catch(this.handleError);
```

}

Now i can easily use the get from the first service in any http request like

```
getChecklists(truckid): Observable<any> {

return this._httpclient.get(this.inspectionurl + "get-checklists")
  .map(res=>res.json().data)
```

}

The above first service retuns an error that flatmap doesnt exist. How do i adjust the first service to be used in another http request and also attach a token from the token event

The two solutions are based on the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183223/custom-http-request-returns-an-error-in-angular2/42183701?noredirect=1#comment71535639_42183701) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185464/ionic2-set-and-retrieve-the-value-of-storage-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you would need a flatmap here, see this link:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Only if your responses are observables and you want to merge the stream would you use that, which I don't think is your objective here.

So your 'get' function on the HttpClient would become:

```
      get(url){
          let headers = new Headers();
          this.createGeneralHeaders(headers);

          return this.http.get(`${url}?access-token=${this.authtoken}`, {headers});               
      }
```